# Unable to retireve objects from Mongoose-Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Mongodb database with resume objects like below. I am using a node-express server. And I am querying the mongo database to get objects based on a specific skill. For example: If I query for a skill: jquery, only objects with that skill is returned. The problem is with the get function that is returning objects from the database.

In the highlighted code: If I directly insert the object like:

```
Resume.find({skills.jQuery : 2},function(err, results){...}
```

then I get the expected results.

However if I insert it dynamically (skillSet), then it doesnot work. Iit checked the value for skillSet and it give me what I expect('skills.JQuery')

```
var skillSet = ("'"+'skills.' + req.params.skill +"'");
console.log('skillSet',skillSet) //'skills.jQuery'
Resume.find({skillSet : 2},function(err, results){
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56031b4353b32084651173fb"),
    "uuid" : "acd06792-87c3-4b0e-827a-8bd19d7f9c03",
    "creationDate" : ISODate("2015-09-23T21:36:03.728Z"),
    "status" : "3",
    "name" : "resume_dev",
    "__v" : 0,
    "skills" : {
        "node" : 2,
        "react" : 2,
        "React" : 3,
        "JQUERY" : 2,
        "JavaScript" : 15,
        "JQuery" : 5,
        "Backbone" : 3,
        "Node" : 2,
        "Angular" : 4,
        "Javascript" : 2,
        "jQuery" : 17,
        "javascript" : 3
    }
}

router.get('/skills/:skill', function(req, res){
    console.log("req.params.skill",req.params.skill);
    var skillSet = ("'"+'skills.' + req.params.skill +"'");
    console.log('skillSet',skillSet) //skills.react
    Resume.find({skillSet : 2},function(err, results){
        console.log('hi');
        console.log(skillSet)
        console.log(results);
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json(err);
        }
        else {
            //   console.log("====>",results);
            res.status(200).json(results);
            //  res.render('status',{Resume: JSON.stringify(results)});
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I understand your question correctly, you can do something like this:

```
var query = {};
query['skills.' + req.params.skill] = 2;
Resume.find(query,function(err, results){
    // Do something with the callback
};
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to get all numbers greater or equal to 1, you will need *$gte*. Here are the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/). This is the updated query:

```
var query = {};
query['skills.' + req.params.skill] = {$gte: 1};
Resume.find(query,function(err, results){
    // Do something with the callback
};
```

Comment: This works, just that I am trying to query for a skill >= 1. Basically if the skill  is available in the object, I want to return the object. query['skills.' + req.params.skill] >= 1 doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Thats what I was looking for {$gte: 1}. Thanks a ton!!